# Trying to show # of steps in my android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a step counter app that connects with google firebase. The user will be asked to log in and then once they do it sends them to the code below. I am fairly new to android development. For some reason, the number of steps does not show. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
Button btnLogOut;
TextView stepBox;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
int steps = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sSensor= sensorManager .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    stepBox = findViewById(R.id.TV_STEPS);
    btnLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);
    btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            Intent I = new Intent(UserActivity.this, ActivityLogin.class);
            startActivity(I);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    float[] values = event.values;
    int value = -1;

    if (values.length > 0) {
        value = (int) values[0];
    }


    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR) {
        steps++;
       
    }
    stepBox.setText(String.valueOf(steps));
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    //won't happen
}
```

}

**Here is the XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="edu.binghamton.pparmar.UserActivity">


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="409dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="110dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="116dp"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV_STEPS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#3D6CFC"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Steps Count" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Logout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogOut"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="151dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV_CALORIES"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/calories"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#3D6CFC"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:text="Today's Burnt Calories" />

</LinearLayout>
```